# Scala trouble accessing Java methods

Tags: java, scala, interop

So, I have something written in Java, and I want to extend it in Scala...  The issue I'm running into is that Scala isn't seeing methods I need.

Here is how it's set up:
Player extends Mob, and Mob extends Entity.

I need to access a method in Player that isn't defined in Mob or Entity, but Scala doesn't think it exists even though Java does.

It can see methods defined by Mob and Entity just fine.  Also, all the methods I'm talking about are non-static.

So, am I doing something wrong, or is this a limitation imposed by Scala?

Edit --
Here is the relevant code:

```
package test

import rsca.gs.model.Player

object Test {
     def handle(p:Player): Unit = {
         p.getActionSender().sendTeleBubble(0, 0, false);
     }
}
```

Player class:

```
package rsca.gs.model;        
    // imports        
public final class Player extends Mob {
        //  Implemented methods (not going to post them, as there are quite a few)    
        // Relevant code
        private MiscPacketBuilder actionSender;
        public MiscPacketBuilder getActionSender() {
        return actionSender;
    }
}
```

Error:
value getActionSender is not a member of rsca.gs.model.Player

Comment: Posted some, but the spacing got mangled.  Sorry about that.

Comment: And what is Scala failing to see `getActionSender()` or `sendTeleBubble(0, 0, false);`?

Comment: what happens? It doesn't compile? Does it throw an exception at runtime? What's the error you get?

Comment: Oh, and dumb question, but are Player, Mob and Entity in the classpath?

Comment: It doesn't see getActionSender.  The error is: value getActionSender is not a member of rsca.gs.model.Player

Comment: And yes, they're all in the classpath.  I imported the JAR containing all of them.

Comment: Please read about codeformatting here. In short: Don't use anything you know from home. Especially not `<pre><code>` insert your code as is, mark it, hit the code button (watch that fancy tooltip!) `{}`. Other SE-pages use a 010110-Button, to keep your brain moving. And look at the nice instant-preview below your post. If it looks ugly, it is ugly, it will be ugly. Thanks for listening; bye, bye. By the way - what was the question? :)

Comment: *So, I have something written in Java, and I want to extend it in Scala...*

AFAIK, you have a class Player in Java - that is Javacode. And from there, maybe you access scala, but not the other way round. Or what am I missing? 

We don't see the command line, we don't see the errormessage, Test doesn't extend anything - it **uses** a Player.

Comment: Exactly...  I'm just trying to use methods from Java classes, and they're invisible for whatever reason.

Comment: can you try aliasing player to make sure there's no other "player" class in scope? `import rsca.gs.model.{ Player=> JPlayer }` and then change Player with JPlayer in your test class

Comment: Same error.  Also, I didn't even know you could do that; that's pretty cool.

Comment: We like to see your command line for compilation, as well as the errorcode in full, beautiful length. Thanks.

Comment: Did you misspell something, like the name of the method?  The fact that you're getting "Error: value getActionSender is not a member of rsca.gs.model.Player" and not "test/Test.scala:3: error: Player is not a member of rsca.gs.model" implies that it knows about your Player class.

Comment: I'm not using the command line, I'm using Eclipse, so it handles all of that for me.

No, it recognizes the class, but it hides everything that the parent methods don't have.

Comment: @RandomGuy12345, could you start the scala interpreter pointing to your jar and see if you can create a object of type Player and call its method?
`scala -classpath your.jar`

Answer (score 2):

I never encountered such problems, and you probably checked your configuration and everything else twice, so I would guess this is some Eclipse related build issue. You should try to build from the command line in order to see whether Scala or Eclipse is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to run a test against the class just to see if you got the right one?

```
p.getClass.getMethods
```

... and if possible (may run into NPE) in order to find the source:

```
p.getClass.getProtectionDomain.getCodeSource.getLocation.getPath
```

Answer (score 0):

When compiling the Scala class, do something like this:

```
scalac *.scala *.java
```

This way, Scala will look a the Java code to see what is available. If, however, the Java code is already compiled and provided as a jar file, just add it to the classpath used when compiling the Scala code.

Comment: That doesn't fix it, and Eclipse handles it just fine.  There are no errors in Eclipse that indicate that it failed adding it to the classpath, etc.

Comment: @RandomGuy Oh... Eclipse... there are bugs with Eclipse. I'd look up Eclipse threads.