# type definition in a package object "hijacking" the inheritance of a java class in scala code

Tags: java, scala, inheritance, package

I have the following situation:

I have a Java class hierarchy like this:

```
package org.foo.some;
public class Model extends org.foo.some.GenericModel { // ... }

package org.bar;
public class MyModel extends org.foo.some.Model { // ... }
```

where `org.foo.some.Model` and `org.foo.some.GenericModel` are out of my reach (not my code). In Scala, also out of my reach, there is:

```
package org {
  package foo {
    package object some {
      type Model = org.foo.some.ScalaModel
    }
  }
}
```

This leads to a funny behavior in Scala code, e.g.

```
val javaModel:MyModel = new org.bar.MyModel()

trait FooTrait[T <: org.foo.some.GenericModel] { // ... }

class FooClass extends FooTrait[MyModel] { //... }
```

does not compile and raises the following error:

> type arguments [org.bar.MyModel] do not conform to trait FooTrait's type
>   parameter bounds [T <: org.foo.some.GenericModel]

Further, I can't invoke any method of `org.foo.some.Model` nor of `org.foo.some.GenericModel` on `javaModel`:

```
javaModel.doSomething()
```

raises

> value create is not a member of org.bar.MyModel

I am under the impression that the package object is "hijacking" the visibility of the Java class hierarchy in Scala code. Indeed, `ScalaModel` does not extend `org.foo.some.GenericModel`.

Is there maybe a way to still access the hierarchy from within Scala code?

**Edit:** when re-compiling the code out of my reach and removing the type re-definition, everything works. So I think what I'm looking at is a way to "disable" an package-level type definition for a specific class.

Comment: Does FooClass extend FooTrait? Your code sample certainly doesn't say so.

Comment: You should provide a compiling example. Your question does not show what package `public class Model extends org.foo.some.GenericModel` is defined in... To me it just seems it should be defined in *your* package `org.bar` and have `public class MyModel extends org.bar.Model`.

Comment: thanks, the question was missing quite some important points: `org.foo.some.GenericModel` and `org.foo.some.Model` are both out of my reach and in a different package than `org.bar.MyModel`; `FooClass` extends `FooTrait[MyModel]`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a GUI (in particular Eclipse) to build your project?

This seems related to [Scala trouble accessing Java methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822252/scala-trouble-accessing-java-methods) (that has no answer but where the general consensus is that the problem is not with scala but with Eclipse).

Comment: I'm using IDEA and there things actually look fine. Now that you mention it tough, I'll double-check the build process.

Comment: Double-checked, the issue is not with eclipse or IDEA. When recompiling the framework code without the type re-definition, things work just fine.